# How do I add variable to pynput

Tags: python, variables, module, pyautogui, pynput

```
#import modules
from pynput.keyboard import *
import time
import pyautogui

#Ask user for ID and Pass
ID = int(input('Enter ID: '))
Pass = int(input('Enter Pass: '))

#Enable controller
k = Controller()


#Press and Release 'win.key'
k.press(Key.cmd)
k.release(Key.cmd)
time.sleep(1)

#Typing "zoom" with a tim.sleep
time.sleep(0.1)
k.press('z')
k.release('z')
time.sleep(0.1)
k.press('o')
k.release('o')
time.sleep(0.1)
k.press('o')
k.release('o')
time.sleep(0.1)
k.press('m')
k.release('m')
time.sleep(0.1)

#Execute enter key
k.press(Key.enter)
k.release(Key.enter)
time.sleep(2)

#Postion for mouse click
x=501
y=291

#Move mouse to position
pyautogui.moveTo(x, y, duration = 2)

#Click on the position
pyautogui.click()

#Enter Zoom credentials
k.type(ID)
k.type(Pass)
```

The last 2 lines throw an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/rijul/Desktop/PyCharm Projects/learningclass.py", line 50, in 
k.type(ID)
File "C:\Users\rijul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard_base.py", line 461, in type
for i, character in enumerate(string):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

> P.S. You will need to have zoom installed for this to work...

Answer (score 0):

```
ID = int(input('Enter ID: '))
Pass = int(input('Enter Pass: '))
```

The variables take the input as `integers` but the `k.type` requires strings.

One way to solve this is to make it a string - `str(ID)`

Comment: Alright,now the error is gone but the k.type function still doesn't type in the user input

Comment: Does the application use directX?

Comment: But does it matter? @TheLaggytablet

Comment: I think so, since, if the game uses directX, it won't take normal keystrokes.

Comment: and for that reason, there's a module for directX to help. - [here the link](https://pypi.org/project/PyDirectInput/)

Comment: So should I do a ```pydirectinput.type(ID)```?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're passing wrong parameters as k.type is looking for `string` value whereas you're passing an `integer`. In nutshell, you should make `ID` and `Pass` as a `string` in place of an `integer`.

```
ID = input('Enter ID: ')
Pass = input('Enter Pass: ')
```

Comment: Alright,now the error is gone but the k.type function still doesn't type in the user input

Answer (score 0):

Change the last two lines

```
k.type(str(ID))
k.type(str(Pass))
```